# iOS UILabel not changing when power is disconnected

Tags: ios5, notifications, uilabel, nsnotificationcenter, uidevice

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    device.batteryMonitoringEnabled = YES;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification" object:device];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification" object:device];
}

- (void)batteryChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    NSLog(@"State: %i Charge: %f", device.batteryState, device.batteryLevel);
    batteryLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"State: %i Charge: %f", device.batteryState, device.batteryLevel];
}
```

The UILabel is never updated. The event for the power source is never fired.

Am I doing something wrong?

I plan on only supporting iOS 5.x and 6

Comment: really never? did you make a long term test (several hours)?

Comment: my battery was at 70% and it's suppose to trigger every 5% or 1 minute. but im close to 100% and the UILabel never changed

Comment: i got the Notification Center working but the UILabel is not updating.

Comment: Maybe the notification is not on the main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IBOutlet UILabel *currentBatteryStatusLabel;
```

I changed the above code into the following and everything started working.

```
__weak IBOutlet UILabel *currentBatteryStatusLabel;
```

I am not sure why it makes such a big difference

Answer (score 0):

If you get the notification center working, but the UILabel isn't updating, isn't it simply because the app is in background when the notification is received?

I would try the following:

1. See if the uilabel is correctly connected to the storyboard
2. Update the uilabel once the app is awakened from sleep

Comment: The app is not in the background. I have the screen set to never sleep (via Settings) and I have been actively observing it. I did finally get it working by modifying the outlet to have __weak in front